Creating a timescaleDB Materialized view with a sql transaction fails
I am trying to do a continous integration with timescaleDB but is impossible to create a materialized view directly from my code i get the error:
ERROR:  CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ... WITH DATA cannot run inside a transaction block
Is it possible for me to setup the view directly from my code? Instead of using the terminal to create the view?
sql_create_table = """
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bin1s (
    time TIMESTAMP,
    symbol VARCHAR(50),
    price NUMERIC,
    qty INTEGER
);
"""

sql_aggregate = """
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ohlc_data_minute
WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
SELECT symbol,
   time_bucket(INTERVAL '1 minute', time) AS date,
   FIRST(price, time) as open,
   MAX(price) as high,
   MIN(price) as low,
   LAST(price, time) as close,
   SUM(qty) as volume
FROM bin1s
GROUP BY symbol, date;
"""
sql_create_hypertable = "SELECT create_hypertable('bin1s', 'time');"

sql_create_index = "CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ix_symbol_time ON bin1s (symbol, time DESC);"



async def connect_to_database():
    while True:
        try:

            await asyncio.sleep(1)

            connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres", password="password", host="timescaledb", port="5432", database="postgres")
            cursor = connection.cursor()

            cursor.execute("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'bin1s')")
            table_exists = cursor.fetchone()[0]

            if not table_exists:
                cursor.execute(sql_create_table)
                cursor.execute(sql_create_hypertable)
                cursor.execute(sql_create_index)
                connection.commit()
                cursor.execute(sql_aggregate)
                connection.commit()
                print("Table 'bin1s' created successfully!")
            else:
                print("Table 'bin1s' already exists. Skipping table creation.")

            print("Database setup successful")
            return cursor, connection
        except psycopg2.Error as e:
            print(f"Error connecting to database: {e}")
            print("Retrying in 1 second...")

        # Retry after 1 second
        await asyncio.sleep(1)



I see you already introduced a commit before create the sql aggregate and I was sure that it was the solution.
You should set autoCommit=True. Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74748522/pyscopg2-without-transaction
